# lettuce seeds germination in Petri dishes

Tags: houseplants, vegetables, germination

I dipped lettuce seeds in distilled water for 12 hours than transfer it to Petri dishes that having Whatman filter paper double folded and moisten with distilled water.After that i give 72 hours continuous light but seeds cannot germinate.

What the reason behind this?

Comment: Are you trying to grow lettuce or is this a science project? Sounds more like biology than gardening.

Comment: Yes,this is science project.

Answer (score 2):

Have you also placed a cover over the damp filter paper with the seed? If not, the seeds may actually be drying and this would keep them from germinating.

Also, I'm sure you realize that continuous light is not necessary (else there would be no lettuce in the world!). Lettuce seeds are also know to no germinate if they get too hot, so set your covered petri dish out of direct sunlight.

Lastly, seeds are not guaranteed to germinate within 3 days at 70F, so be patient. It might take as long as a couple of weeks. Just be sure the seeds remain damp and not in complete darkness.

Comment: Thanks.After this i start the experiment again.Now, i dipped the lettuce seeds in distilled water for 12 hours.Than transfer it to petridishes that having whatman double folded filter paper and moisten with distilled water. Petridishes were then left in room for 72 hours(Petridishes are cover with transparent glass). After 72 hours,when i check the petridishes only small radical come out from seeds and no hypocotyl arises.I left the petridishes for further 2 days.When i check the seeds after 2 days there is no further growth.Is there is problem in seeds?

Comment: Problem could also be too much water. Seeds like their oxygen.